# xcode 4.3 - storyboard - iAd

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard, iad

I am using a storyboard and I have added iAd banner to my view. I have no problem with displaying the banner but before the banner display it has a white background which looks odd.

how can I maintain my original background before and if no ad is being served instead of the white background?

I have looked for many codes and tutorial and all of them do not solve this issue. any idea?

Comment: Not an Xcode question. You should edit the title A) to be a question B) to say what version of iOS you are developing for C) remove the reference to Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in the `viewController` that is responsible to show the ad, you adopt the delegate `ADBannerViewDelegate`, there is a method that notifies you when the ad is loaded, and ready to be displayed.

> ```
> - bannerViewDidLoadAd:
> ```

You can hide the ad or remove it from the view, and once you get notified that the ad is ready, add it back to the view.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/ADBannerViewDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009581

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH4-SW9

---

**Edit:**
This is from Apple:

> **Responding When an Advertisement Loads**
>
> The iAd framework makes it easy
>   to adopt an asynchronous model and only display an ad when one is
>   available. Your application should never display an empty banner view.
>   Instead, it should show the banner when an advertisement is available
>   and hide the banner when it has nothing to show.
>
> When a banner view has a new advertisement to display, it calls the
>   delegate's bannerViewDidLoadAd: method. This method is called even if
>   the banner view is not currently part of the view hierarchy. Your
>   application can use this method to add the view to a view hierarchy or
>   to move the banner view on screen. “Banner View Sizes” uses a property
>   to track whether the banner view is visible. If the banner is not
>   visible and a new advertisement is loaded, the method animates the
>   view onto the screen.
>
> Listing 2-2  Animating in the banner view after a new advertisement is
>   loaded
>
> ```
> - (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner 
> { 
>     if (!self.bannerIsVisible) 
>     { 
>         [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL]; 
> // Assumes the banner view is just off the bottom of the screen. 
>         banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height); 
>         [UIView commitAnimations]; 
>         self.bannerIsVisible = YES; 
>     } 
> }
> ```